# CSV with spaces around the comma

Tags: python, csv

Assume I have a CSV file with spaces around the comma:

```
'1','2','3',   '4'
'5','6','7',   '8'
```

If I use the Python CSV package, the `4` and `8` values are treated differently:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/nums.csv','rU') as fin:
...    for row in csv.reader(fin,quotechar="'"):
...       print row
... 
['1', '2', '3', "   '4'"]
['5', '6', '7', "   '8'"]
```

Is there a way to fix this using the CSV module? I know that I can read and parse the file myself, but I am interested if there is a dialect setting in the CSV package to fix this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set [`skipinitialspace` to `True`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace) to skip any whitespace following a delimiter:

> When `True`, whitespace immediately following the *delimiter* is ignored. The default is `False`.

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> demo='''\
... '1','2','3',   '4'
... '5','6','7',   '8'
... '''
>>> for row in csv.reader(demo.splitlines(True), skipinitialspace=True, quotechar="'"):
...     print row
... 
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['5', '6', '7', '8']
```

Comment: Doh! I read that section 3 times and still did not see this. Thanks! This works!